# Ajax is sending 2 calls on button press - issue rises in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have an ajax function who is sending 2 call on button press and sending emails 2 times then. This issues happens in some chrome version. On some chromes it works fine as well.

Here is the ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sbtBtn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>assets/common/getCartInfo.php",
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#coverForm').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#sbtBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#response").css("display", "block");
                    },
        success: function(){
            $("#response").css("display", "none");
            $("#coverLetter").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#sbtBtn").css("display", "none");
            $("#coverForm").submit();
                    }
            })
        });
    });
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="limited">
      <p class="limited-title">Message to Receiver</p>
      <form name="coverForm" id="coverForm" action="<?php echo WEB_URL.'payment/'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <textarea name="coverLetter" required="required" id="coverLetter" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="button" style="display: block;" name="sbtBtn" id="sbtBtn" value="Continue">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="response" style="display: none;">
      <p>Please Wait While Your Transaction Is Being Processed</p>
    </div>
```

Here is my PHP emailing code from which I have emails 2 times.

```
$body         = 'I am testing problem';
$to           = 'msklodhi2005@gmail.com';
$subject      = "Company Subject";
$Mail_header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL; 
$Mail_header .=  "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".PHP_EOL;
$Mail_header .= "From: Company <somecompany@somecompany.com>".PHP_EOL;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $Mail_header);
```

Comment: how is the page loaded? maybe it has added 2 handler of ($("#sbtBtn").click(function(){)

Comment: Page doesn't reloads it simple submits my form in the success. It has only one handler Sir.

Comment: tried changing the Jquery handler with a javascript function?

Comment: can you post all generated code in browser source on pastebin

Comment: No Sir, I didn't tried using javascript function. How that can be changed?

Comment: @Saqueib: http://pastebin.com/DuyyGXwW

Comment: no, i need source of rendered page, right click on page and select `view page source`

Comment: and get rid of `language="javascript"` attribute in script tag

Comment: Make sure you don't have referenced this script files two times in the page.

Comment: @Saqueib: http://pastebin.com/qVHUKK7B

Comment: @Saqueib I have removed: `language="javascript"`

Comment: @Jai I have made sure this as well. Thank You.

Comment: @Testing are you getting 2 ajax calls in console timeline, plz post screen shot

Comment: @Saqueib Yes I am getting 2 ajax calls in console.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML code to:

```
<div class="limited">
    <p class="limited-title">Message to Receiver</p>
    <form name="coverForm" id="coverForm" action="<?php echo WEB_URL.'payment/'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <textarea name="coverLetter" required="required" id="coverLetter" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>

        <!--Remove your submit button-->
    </form>
    <button style="display: block;" name="sbtBtn" id="sbtBtn">Continue</button>
</div>

<div id="response" style="display: none;">
    <p>Please Wait While Your Transaction Is Being Processed</p>
</div>
```

Probabily chrome is submiting your form and triggering your ajax call.

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem. You could also add `return false` to the click handler to prevent the default submit action.

Comment: No! that wouldn't be the issue because of `type="button"` as OP has used.

Comment: Let me try and I will get back to you. Thank you please.

Comment: @Jai so changing HTML can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it, you are submitting form again on `ajax success` callback

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#sbtBtn").click(function(e){
    //Prevent default         
    e.preventDefault(); // Add this to prevent Default action 

    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>assets/common/getCartInfo.php",
      async: true,
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#coverForm').serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#sbtBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#response").css("display", "block");
                },
      success: function(){
        $("#response").css("display", "none");
        $("#coverLetter").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#sbtBtn").css("display", "none");
        //$("#coverForm").submit(); // remove this it will submit form again
        }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: But its button how can button can submit form? I mean its not submit button its simple button. What do you say?

Comment: My purpose is only to submit the hidden values in the form and nothing to work around with this line of code.

Comment: you are already submitting form using `$.ajax` so no need to call `submit()` method again in success callback, check the updated code

Comment: @Testing about button, you have a `click` event handler on `$("#sbtBtn")` that's why its submitting the form as `data: $('#coverForm').serialize()`, Just use updated answer code, it will work